# JavaFX Notifications эффект во время отображения

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите, возможно ли убрать эффект в время отображения уведомления?

Comment: Ты про эту библиотеку? https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification

Comment: Точно. Я не указал библиотеку - controlsfx.

Comment: В коде намека на такую возможность не заметил. Ты пробовал присвоить setAnimationType(null) если нет, то увы. Разве что можно включить Animations.POPUP, а то SLIDE действительно какой-то дурацкий. Но спасибо за инфу, я об этой либе не знал.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не нашел ничего подобного. 
https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html